# How to read data out of the Health app in the iOS 11 Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I'm writing some integration UI tests now that iOS 11 allows you to test multiple applications, the goal being to verify the data my app enters from inside the Health app. I'm most of the way there, but there's one attribute I can't figure out how to check. Below I've given a screenshot of the simulator, and the accessibility inspector's assessment of the table view cell in question.

I'm looking to check the **Was User Entered** field, to see if it says "Yes" or "No". All my attempts have failed. I can find the "Was User Entered" with the line below, but it doesn't look like there's any way to jump to the containing UI element:

```
let wasUserEntered = app.windows.staticTexts["Was User Entered"]
```

I've tried looking for "Was User Entered, Yes", like the accessibility inspector shows, but that doesn't find anything.

How can I do this? Surely it's exposed for accessibility purposes.

[image: Health App screen]

[image: Accessibility Inspector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find cells containing a static text with an identifier, like so:

```
let wasUserEntered = app.tables.cells.containing(.staticText, identifier:"Was User Entered").staticTexts["Yes"].exists
```